# undefined is not an object '_react2.PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult'

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, react-native-ios

I am currently running ReactNative version 0.54.0.  I have scoured the internet and followed all of the directions to setting up PushNotification ([manual linking](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios.html#manual-linking): adding RCTPushNotification.xcodeproj to xcode and linking up the libRCTPushNotification, etc)

I copied the code from [facebook](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios.html#content), into the AppDelegate.m in xCode

I have imported PushNotificationIOS from react and PushNotification from react-native-push-notification.

I copied the [PushNotification.configure()](https://apiko.com/blog/react-native-push-notifications/) code into my app.js file.  The error that I keep getting is "**undefined is not an object '_react2.PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult**'" in the onNotification method.

Can anyone let me know I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have imports like these

import {
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    PushNotificationIOS
} from 'react-native';

and not

import {
    StyleSheet,
    View
} from 'react-native';
import {PushNotificationIOS} from 'react-native';

Comment: Thanks, I found out I had put: 

import {  PushNotificationIOS } from 'react';